# RTK Query endpoints not working for single product get query

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

I am not able to fetch the single product details through Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query but get all products is working but not for single product.

[image]
[image]

constants.js:

```js
export const BASE_URL='/';
export const PRODUCTS_URL='api/products/';
export const ORDERS_URL='api/orders';
export const USERS_URL='api/users';
export const PAYPAL_URL='api/config/paypal';
```

`useGetProductsQuery` is fetching all the products from the api but the `useGetProductDetailsQuery` is not fetching single product details

Store:

```js
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { apiSlice } from './slices/apiSlice';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer
  },
  middleware:(getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
  devTools: true
})

export default store;
```

apiSlice:

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { BASE_URL, PRODUCTS_URL } from '../constants';

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: BASE_URL });

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQuery,
  tagTypes: ["Product", "Order","User"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getProducts: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: PRODUCTS_URL,
      }),
      keepUnusedDataFor: 5
    }),
    getProductDetails: builder.query({
      query: (productId) => ({
        url: `${PRODUCTS_URL}/${productId}`, // this url is not hitting the api and not fetching the data, but in postman its working fine
      }),
      keepUnusedDataFor: 5
    }),
  })
});

export const {
  useGetProductDetailsQuery,
  useGetProductsQuery
} = apiSlice;
```

Product Screen:

```
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Col, Row, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Rating from "../components/Rating";
import { useGetProductDetailsQuery } from "../slices/apiSlice";

const ProductScreen = () => {
  const { id: productId } = useParams();
  console.log(useGetProductDetailsQuery(productId))
  const { data: product, isLoading, Error } = useGetProductDetailsQuery(productId);

  return (
    <>
      <Link className="btn btn-light my-3" to="/">Go Back</Link>
      <Row>
        <Col md={5}>
          <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
        </Col>
        <Col md={4}>
          <ListGroup variant="flush">
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h3>{product.name}</h3>
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <Rating value={product.rating} text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`} />
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              Price: ${product.price}
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              Description: {product.description}
            </ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Col>
        <Col md={3}>
          <Card>
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Price:</Col>
                  <Col>
                    <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Status:</Col>
                  <Col>
                    <strong>{product.countInStock>0?"In Stock":"Out of Stock"}</strong>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Button type="button" className="btn-block" disabled={product.countInStock===0}>
                  Add To Cart
                </Button>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  )
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.26.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have also added the proxy. I don't know why its not getting the product details.

Comment: Do you know what, or where, specifically isn't working as expected? What debugging steps have been taken? Are there any errors in the console? Is the network request being made? If so, how is it resolving? If you get a response back, is it what you expect? Is the store updated as expected? We need a bit more context what the specific issue is. Saying "it's not working" isn't very illuminating. Can you [edit] to provide more details? The only overt issue I see is the UI code not checking if `product` is actually defined/populated, e.g. if any data has actually been fetched.

Comment: Hi Drew, useGetProductDetailsQuery is not returning the product details from the API.
Where useGetProductQuery is working fine returning all the products, where as useGetProductDetailsQuery is not returning the single product based on the product id

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')
    at ProductScreen (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1120:24)

Comment: Yeah, I got that much. I'm asking for details between when the app makes the network request to *get* that data, and the UI where it's "not there". Ah yeah, about that error, see the last line of my initial comment. So is the error preventing the UI from getting the fetched data? Can you see it in the Redux state? Do you have the redux dev-tools and extension installed?

Comment: when I am making a call to the api through RTK its not hitting the api for single product.
Where as when I am making the call throught RTK for all products its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned `data` property will be undefined until the query actually completes and has fetched data to provide. The UI code you have makes the assumption that `data` is defined.

See the query hook's [signature](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#signature), specifically the properties dealing with data and query status:

> ```
> // Derived request status booleans
> isUninitialized: boolean // Query has not started yet.
> isLoading: boolean // Query is currently loading for the first time. No data yet.
> isFetching: boolean // Query is currently fetching, but might have data from an earlier request.
> isSuccess: boolean // Query has data from a successful load.
> isError: boolean // Query is currently in an "error" state.
> ```

You will want to at least check that `data` is defined prior to attempting to access into it for nested properties like `data.image`. The `isSuccess` is also a flag that indicates the query has data.

Example:

```
const ProductScreen = () => {
  const { id: productId } = useParams();
  const {
    data: product,
    isLoading,
    error
  } = useGetProductDetailsQuery(productId);

  if (!product) {
    return null; // or some fallback UI message about no data, etc
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Link className="btn btn-light my-3" to="/">Go Back</Link>
      <Row>
        <Col md={5}>
          <Image
            src={product.image} // <-- now safe to access
            alt={product.name}
            fluid
          />
        </Col>
        ...
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductScreen;
```

Comment: Thanks!!! @Drew Reese for the help this means a lot :)
Actually, I was stuck on this problem from last 3 days, I was not able to figure out the issue.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Problem was I forgot to check,
 if (!product) {
    return null; // or some fallback UI message about no data, etc
  }
what you have mention above...